# How to wrap react-testing-library and react-router@6 while testing in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-router, redux-toolkit

When `<Create/>` (router path : "/create") page rendered at first, I wanted to test it to see if it worked well, but I think test doesn't work well. I don't know what is wrong, but I think my custom `render` might be error.

```
import { render } from "../../utils/test-utils";

describe("createPage ", () => {
  it("rendering create page", () => {
    render(<Create />, { path: "/create" });
    const button = screen.findByRole("button", { name: "등록" });
    expect(screen.findByTestId("title"));
    expect(button);
  });

  it("change input text ", () => {
    render(<Create />, { path: "/create" });
    const TitleInput = screen.findByRole("textbox");

    user.type(TitleInput, "1");
    waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByText("1")).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
});
```

and test result was succeeded when I changed

```js
  expect(screen.getByText("1")).toBeInTheDocument();
```

to

```js
  expect(screen.getByText("2")).toBeInTheDocument();
```

it means the test results are not affected.

here is test-utils(`render`) code

```
function render(ui, { preloadedState = {}, path, ...renderoptions } = {}) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
              <Route path={path} element={children} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }

  return {
    store,
    ...rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderoptions }),
  };
}
```

When I tried to change this code (add async & await)

```
it("createPage title & content 값 입력", () => {
  render(<Create />, { path: "/create" });

  const TitleInput = screen.findByRole("textbox");

  user.type(TitleInput, "1");
  waitFor(() => {
    expect(screen.getByText("2")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

to

```
it("createPage title & content 값 입력", async () => {
  render(<Create />, { path: "/create" });

  const TitleInput = await screen.findByRole("textbox");

  user.type(await TitleInput, "1");
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(screen.getByText("2")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

I got the error like this

```
Unable to find role="textbox"

Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
<body>
  <div>
    <div
      class="sc-beySbM fdrGAC"  <== it's my index page(path:"/")
    />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't know if there's a logical issue in your testing methods, but generally we use a `MemoryRouter` in unit tests since the tests don't run in a browser environment, e.g. the DOM, they are instead running in a Node environment. Try switching the `BrowserRouter` to the `MemoryRouter` and see what issue persist from there.

Comment: thank you for correcting. now i solved it using MemoryRouter